Lithonia HGX Floodlight is clicking with power off
Installed new Lithonia HGX floodlight, the power is controlled by a switch, switch is off, the photocell makes a constant clicking sound at night with switch turned off.
How do I stop it?
Ready to return it to the store...
Thanks

Does it click with the switch turned on?  Reason for asking is to determine if this is something integral with the electric parts of the light, or if there may be some odd mechanical issue like expansion and contraction from the sun.  It may all be easier solved by returning the light and replacing it.

If you just want the thing to not click, I agree with RMDan: take it back to the store and get another one, perhaps a different company's. Typically these lights don't do anything when the power is off. If you're facing this with scientific curiosity, as in, "Why is this thing clicking?" then please tell us if the clicking gradually stops through the night, or if it keeps clicking all night long until morning. Also if the click is in conjunction with some other repeatable stimulus, like someone walking in front of the light.

Is the switch a normal toggle switch?

If power to the light is controlled with a "switch loop" and/or is indirectly wired so that the neutral is switched instead of the hot, then it could be flowing just enough "phantom power" to the sensor electronics to allow it to start up for a brief time.
